# Spark ML on HdInsight vs Azure machine learning studio?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, azure-machine-learning-service

What are the scenarios where Apache Spark ML on HdInsight is preferred over Azure ML studio?

Answer (score 1):

These are two different offerings from Microsoft. I'll try to explain the differences, but it will be down to what you need. There's also [Azure Databricks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/databricks/) that runs Spark, as well, so that's something to look into if these don't meet your needs.

### Azure ML Studio

- Uses a drag-and-drop interface with no coding required, unless you need to programmatically use the REST API it gives you to call your model.
- A bit limited in terms of the models available and what all data cleaning you can do, but you can execute custom R/Python scripts to do these for you.
- As far as I can tell, this is free to use and play around with but [Azure ML Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning-services/) is what Microsoft is concentrating on in terms of building models for production uses.

### HDInsight with Spark cluster

- Creates a VM with Spark installed on it, which you can SSH into it or run Jupyter notebooks on.
- Allows you to create full big data pipelines by using [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/).
- Gives you SparkML which you build more custom models than you would with Azure ML Studio.
- Can handle streaming data much better than Azure ML Studio.

I think it mainly boils down to do you want to experiment with making a basic model or do you want to build a full big data workflow that will create a machine learning model.

Hope that at least gives you a better idea between the two. If you have more questions, feel free to ask.